# Iphone: outgoing email iCloud account and gmail

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, gmail, mobile-mail

Iphone 5 iOS 6.1 (jaikbroken)

OK, I've been solely using the gmail app for a while now and haven't had any use for the built-in mail app.  Was hoping to run without any mail account on there, but it gets me in trouble for those times some other app wants to send email and finds no mail account.

So finally I was setting up gmail just for outgoing smtp but even doing so it forces me to include incoming imap account and it annoys me just on principal to have local duplicate copies of the last 50 messages I don't need.

So I created an icloud account today so I could sync notes and also just use that now for the sent messages.  iCloud mail is set to forward incoming to gmail, but it wont forward outgoing.  Obviously.

Trying to devise a workaround.  What I want is to have all my mail in gmail. My thinking is something like:

- if possible everything outgoing from icloud gets CC'd to gmail
- set a filter in gmail, maybe everything with  from:(me)@icloud.com and bcc:(me)@gmail.com gets moved to sent mail.

Any thoughts, advice, or better ideas welcomed!

Comment: IS it your goal NOT to use the mail.app at all ?

Comment: @buscar yes.I pretty much don't need iOS mail.app. But that breaks down with most apps that attempt to send email.   I'm open to a workaround for that problem if possible. Tried a few Cydia solutions to make gmail the default mail but they didn't really work.

Comment: Did you consider using the Postfix ?

Comment: Heh. There's a word I haven't heard since college!  Worth a try.

Comment: It is a part of the Mac operating system, but not activated.

Comment: That looks like a great solution. But I just realized youre talking about osx an  im askng about iOS.mentioned in the titles and tags but  Ill edit my post to make that more clear

Comment: UPS.... in my effort to help you i completely missed that :) Let me look up for Postfix on iphone (ios) I think is there as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your iCloud account to send using the Gmail SMTP server.

`Setting => Mail, Contacts, Calendar => iCloud => Account => Advanced (Mail) => Outgoing mail server (SMTP) => Other SMTP Serveres => Add Server` here you can set up the Gmail SMTP server: `smtp.gmail.com` - remember to choose the Gmail server, and de-activate the iCloud SMTP server afterwards.

The mails sent will however appear in iCloud's sent folder.

The iCloud sender email address will however still be the iCloud address. If you use the build in Mail.app, you can manually choose your Gmail address (and the mail will appear in Gmail's sent folder), but how you can use this one, the way you want to use it - I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the benefit from using google smtp servers for sending?  You're saying the messages will still appear to come from the @iCloud address and they also won't be in gmail sent folder anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I know this isn't what you are after. - The mail setup on iOS isn't as good it is on e.g. OS X, where you on a normal mail account can define more from mail addresses in the Account settings (mail-1@domain.com, mail-2@domain.com, etc.) but this doesn't work with iOS, not even on a Gmail account (iCloud is totally closed here). On OS X's mail setup you can add a default reply email address, this option is also not available on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

OK, lets make this in a answer.

You might be a good candidate for the Postfix app.

It is already a part of the OS X just not activated.

There are plenty of online instructions how to customized it to your needs.

[Configuring Postfix to Send Mail from Mac OS X Mountain Lion](http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

===============================================

[If you just want to send all of your outgoing mail to some relay server, like the SMTP server of your Internet service provider](https://superuser.com/questions/434687/setting-up-email-for-localhost), you usually need to have a host name for the computer that is sending the mail. This configuration is for a server that is not being used to receive mail.

===============================================

Sometimes we may need to send mails from localhost for testing purposes. That can be easily done using an external Mail client (Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo… ETC) and Postfix, which is the standard email server installed by default in Mac OS X (At least in the latest versions).
[This tutorial is about how to configure Postfix for Mac OS X](http://www.zenddeveloper.com/how-to-send-smtp-mails-with-postfix-mac-os-x-10-8/).

===============================

As I’m constantly trying and changing my default email application on my Mac, I’m currently using Thunderbird, the native email application and also Pilot.

So, decided to use my own local SMTP in order to not store my credentials on each application, and for an easy configuration. Also because I like emails to go fast from y outbox. Then it will be Postfix responsibility to deliver the email properly.

The problem is that my laptop is constantly changing its IP, so most of my emails will not get its destinations if I try to deliver them directly from the Macbook.

What I did, was to [configure postfix to relay on Gmail to deliver my emails](http://www.garron.me/en/mac/postfix-relay-gmail-mac-os-x-local-smtp.html).

Installation

There is nothing to install postfix is already installed on my Mac.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106832/mail-application-which-allow-to-choose-smtp-server/106892#106892 @buscar take a look At this question...